# PHP setlocale doesn't allow PHP functions like strtolower... to work properly for UTF-8?

Tags: php

I tested usage of PHP **setlocale** function with **strtolower** for my standard **UTF-8** encoding and Polish letters.
Unfortunately my experiences showed me that those functions **don't like UTF-8**.
In Windows simply I can't use it.
Well, it turned out I couldn't use it on my host server Linux cp15.vpsi.pl 2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64 neither.
I used locale -a command on that system to find out that I must use **pl_PL.UTF-8** and setlocale function accepted it.
Well, strtolower function could only repeat my entered Polish uppercase letters' string unchanged, find it too difficult to convert Polish letters to lowercase.
This problem doesn't occur for **pl_PL.iso88592**.
As far as I know UTF-8 is the best encoding especially when U use WordPress. Is UTF-8 only available for very sophisticated computer systems?!!!

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

> `strtolower();` doesn't work for polish chars
>
> `<?php strtolower("mĄkA"); ?>`
>
> will return: *mĄka*
>
> the best solution - use `mb_strtolower()`
>
> `<?php mb_strtolower("mĄkA",'UTF-8'); ?>`
>
> will return: *mąka*

Answer (score 1):

Use [mb_strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) function. this will work.

Comment: Good solution. Thank you. Well, setlocale doesn't work only on strtolower like functions.  How about case-insensitive functions like **str_ireplace** ?

Comment: You'll find a complete list of multibyte string functions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 0):

mb_ functions r good. A pity my php.exe (for cmd.exe in Win7 - cli) hasn't got this module and can't recognise those functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'pl_PL.UTF-8');
    $str = iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//translit', $str);
    $str = strtolower($str);
```

See [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.iconv.php)